# What options in async-profiler should I use when I want to analyze offheap leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, async-profiler

I'd like to figure out the cause of native memory leak (off-heap).

I came across a tool called [async-profiler](https://github.com/async-profiler/async-profiler). But, i don't know which option i should use

Regarding of off-heap, `-e` option i know is as below.

- `mmap`
- `malloc`
- `mprotect`
- `nativemem` (known as experimental mode)

flame graph results were different in each option.

#### `mmap` option flame graph result

[image]

#### `malloc` option flame graph result

[image]

**I don't know how to analyze about these results.
What is the difference between each option?**